# Python Newbie Challenge - Looking for a better approach

Tags: python-2.7

As a Python learning exercise, I created a script to scrape and log the status from my cable modem's admin pages, to allow me to look at the modem's status over time.  The script is functional but I would like to improve the efficiency, especially with the function below, which needs to log the stats for each downstream channel, using regular expressions to strip out the non-numeric characters from the data points I'm collecting.

As you can see, it uses a lot of near similarly named variables to deal with the sets of stats for each downstream channel.  I know there's got to be a much slicker way of accomplishing the same task, but am not proficient enough yet to figure it out.

If anyone could offer a better approach to jumpstart my Python understanding, I would appreciate it.

```
def log_downstream_signal(soup, con, reading_ts):
    table = soup.find_all('table')[0]  # this is Downstream channel table
    rows = table.find_all('tr')  # get all the rows
    cols = rows[1].find_all('td')
    channelid1 = re.sub('[^0-9]*', '', cols[1].text)
    channelid2 = re.sub('[^0-9]*', '', cols[2].text)
    channelid3 = re.sub('[^0-9]*', '', cols[3].text)
    channelid4 = re.sub('[^0-9]*', '', cols[4].text)
    cols = rows[3].find_all('td')
    snr1 = re.sub('[^0-9]*', '', cols[1].text)
    snr2 = re.sub('[^0-9]*', '', cols[2].text)
    snr3 = re.sub('[^0-9]*', '', cols[3].text)
    snr4 = re.sub('[^0-9]*', '', cols[4].text)
    cols = rows[5].find_all('td')
    #Note the column indices for this row are offset by 1
    power1 = re.sub('[^0-9]*', '', cols[2].text)
    power2 = re.sub('[^0-9]*', '', cols[3].text)
    power3 = re.sub('[^0-9]*', '', cols[4].text)
    power4 = re.sub('[^0-9]*', '', cols[5].text)

    cur = con.cursor()
    sql = "INSERT INTO downstream_log VALUES ('" + reading_ts + \
        "','" + channelid1 + "'," + snr1 + "," + power1 + ")"
    cur.execute(sql)
    sql = "INSERT INTO downstream_log VALUES ('" + reading_ts + \
        "','" + channelid2 + "'," + snr2 + "," + power2 + ")"
    cur.execute(sql)
    sql = "INSERT INTO downstream_log VALUES ('" + reading_ts + \
        "','" + channelid3 + "'," + snr3 + "," + power3 + ")"
    cur.execute(sql)
    sql = "INSERT INTO downstream_log VALUES ('" + reading_ts + \
        "','" + channelid4 + "'," + snr4 + "," + power4 + ")"
    cur.execute(sql)
    cur.close()
    con.commit()
```

Comment: Why are you redefining `channelid` 4 times? That will only give you the last row

Comment: That's not in the "production" version - I was messing around and pasted the wrong version here.  It's fixed now - thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way I can see is with this block of code:

```
  channelid = re.sub('[^0-9]*', '', cols[1].text)
    channelid = re.sub('[^0-9]*', '', cols[2].text)
    channelid = re.sub('[^0-9]*', '', cols[3].text)
    channelid = re.sub('[^0-9]*', '', cols[4].text)
    cols = rows[3].find_all('td')
    snr1 = re.sub('[^0-9]*', '', cols[1].text)
    snr2 = re.sub('[^0-9]*', '', cols[2].text)
    snr3 = re.sub('[^0-9]*', '', cols[3].text)
    snr4 = re.sub('[^0-9]*', '', cols[4].text)
    cols = rows[5].find_all('td')
    power1 = re.sub('[^0-9]*', '', cols[2].text)
    power2 = re.sub('[^0-9]*', '', cols[3].text)
    power3 = re.sub('[^0-9]*', '', cols[4].text)
    power4 = re.sub('[^0-9]*', '', cols[5].text)
```

You could simplify this with for loops and lists

```
channelid, snr, power = [], [], []
channelCols = rows[1].find_all('td')
snrCols = rows[3].find_all('td')
powerCols = rows[5].find_all('td')
for i in range(1, 5):
     channelid.append(re.sub('[^0-9]*', '', channelCols[i].text))
     snr.append(re.sub('[^0-9]*', '', snrCols[i].text))
     power.append(re.sub('[0-9]*', '', powerCols[i+1].text))

cur = con.cursor()
for i in range(0, 4)
     sql = "INSERT INTO downstream_log VALUES ('" + reading_ts + \
    "','" + channelpi[ + "'," + snr[i] + "," + power[i] + ")"
     cur.execute(sql)
cur.close()
con.commit()
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for.  Thank you.